# Why would IMFSourceReader::ReadSample have a buffer or all 0?

Tags: winapi, audio, aac, ms-media-foundation

My overall goal is to read AAC packets from a custom file system, decode to PCM and play with waveoutwrite.

As an intermediate step, I've downloaded alarm_antelope from
 http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/http-aac.htm
and am attempting to use an IMFSourceReader to read and decode.  (Eventually I'll get the source reader to just give me raw samples so I can test using the decoder).

The problem is that it looks like I get a big buffer or all zero entries.

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    hr = MFStartup(MF_VERSION);

//need to read the data from a source somewhere.
IMFSourceReader *pSourceReader;
wchar_t* filename = L"F:\\PINTS\\Alarm_Antelope.aac"; //temp dir of file downloaded from above url
 hr = MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(filename, NULL, &pSourceReader);
if (FAILED(hr)) {       
    return 0; 
}
DWORD dwStreamIndex = MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM;
IMFMediaType *pMediaType = NULL;
hr= MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaType);
pMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio);
pMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_PCM);

hr= pSourceReader->SetCurrentMediaType(  dwStreamIndex, NULL,pMediaType);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    return 0;
}
DWORD dwControlFlags = 0; //no control flag
DWORD pdwActualStreamIndex;
DWORD pdwStreamFlags;
LONGLONG pllTimestamp;
IMFSample *pSample=NULL;

BYTE* outputData = NULL;
DWORD outputSize = 0;
hr = pSourceReader->ReadSample(dwStreamIndex, dwControlFlags, &pdwActualStreamIndex, &pdwStreamFlags, &pllTimestamp, &pSample);
if (hr < 0) 
    return 0;

DWORD ttlLength = 0;
pSample->GetTotalLength(&ttlLength);
IMFMediaBuffer *pimpBufout;
pSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&pimpBufout);
DWORD bufLen = 0;
pimpBufout->GetCurrentLength(&bufLen);

#pragma region experiment with direct source reader             
    BYTE *outData = NULL;
    DWORD outDataLen = 0;

    hr = pimpBufout->Lock(&outData, NULL, &outDataLen);
    printf("\nbefore copy");
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < outDataLen; i++)
    {
        printf("%x", outData[i]);
    }
    outputData = new BYTE[outDataLen];
    memcpy(outputData, outData, outDataLen);
    outputSize = outDataLen/2;//since this is supposed to be SHORTs

    hr = pimpBufout->Unlock();
    printf("\nAfter copy");
    for ( DWORD i = 0; i < outputSize; i++)
    {
        printf("%x", outputData[i]);
    }
#pragma endregion
```

Both print statements just fill out all zero.  Tracing shows no HR codes other than OK. Why would this produce all 0x00 ?  GetBufferByIndex produces the same result.

Comment: I was better off scrapping the above and following this tutorial, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757929%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Which also could not decode the source file, but could handle mediaCodertests .m4a files.

Comment: The first several decoded samples are all 0 in the block. Eventually there is sound and actual data in the output. I'll leave the question because the tutorial it links to is very helpful.